# Multi dimensional loops from 4 existing arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 4 arrays like so:

```
$bidArr(1,2,3,4);
$bnameArr('Dave', 'Jim', 'Amy', 'Jill');
$bPosArr(7,2,8,10);
$bDayArr('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Saturday');
```

What I would like to know how to do is combine these 4 arrays into one multi-dimensional array like so:

```
$allArr = array  (
  array(1,'Dave',7,'Monday'),
  array(2,'Jim',2,'Tuesday'),
  array(3,'Amy',8,'Wednesday'),
  array(4,'Jill',10,'Saturday)
);
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#example-5526) by passing `null` instead of a callback:

```
$arrAll = array_map( null, $bidArr, $bnameArr, $bPosArr, $bDayArr );
```

[Demo](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/UPba6a)