# Print respective index value from two arrays in " Javascript " and in " PHP "

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, indexing, printing

Print respective index value from two arrays in  " Javascript " and in "PHP"

```
var  a = [ x , y , z] 
var b = [ p, q, r]
```

`then =>  values [x, p] , [ y, q]`

please help me,  Thanks you

Comment: How it should be in " php " please ....

Comment: Create a separate question for the same.

Comment: One of many PHP dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460680/multi-dimensional-loops-from-4-existing-arrays  One of many JS dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32937181/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or just straight forward:

```
x=[ "x" , "y" , "z"];
y=[ "p" , "q" , "r"];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
  alert('value at index [' + i + '] is: [' + x[i] + '] and [' + y[i] + ']');
}
```

as per comment in PHP:

```
$x= array("x" , "y" , "z");
$y= array("p" , "q" , "r");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($x); ++$i) {
    echo $x[$i];
    echo $y[$i];
}
```

also check this excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046892/how-to-print-two-array-at-the-same-time-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`Array.prototypr.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**. See below code

In php it should be like this.

```
$a=array("x","y","z");
$b=array("p","q","r");
$c=array_map(null,$a,$b);
print_r($c);
```

```js
x=[ "x" , "y" , "z"];
y=[ "p" , "q", "r"];

console.log(x.map((x1,i)=>{return [x1,y[i]]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [ 'x' ,'y' , 'z'];
b = [ 'p', 'q', 'r']
 var newArray = a.map(function(val,index){return [val,b[index]]});
 console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const daysNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const daysNames = [
  "monday",
  "tuesday",
  "wednesday",
  "thursday",
  "friday",
  "saturday",
  "sunday"
];

daysNums.map((num, index) => {
  const f = [num, daysNames[index]];
  console.log(f);
});
```